# Is it possible to create a plotly animated 3D scatter plot of mediapipe's body pose landmarks and connections?

Tags: python, plotly, mediapipe

I am currently working on a project where I am using the mediapipe's body pose estimation library, I know that using plotly we can create animated 3D scatter plots.
I was wondering if it's possible to create a animated plot of the body pose landmarks and connections provided by mediapipe using plotly ?

It would be same like the mediapipe's in-built functionality :

```
mp_draw.plot_landmarks()
```

But with plotly's interactivity and animated timeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- take a look at code for `mp_draw.plot_landmarks()` it is using **matplotlib**.  Hence a **plotly** version can be coded
- have done this, this version returns a **plotly** figure.  code I'm sure can be further cleaned up
- animations could be built by building up frames across multiple results

### setup

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from pathlib import Path
import mediapipe as mp

uploaded = {
    Path.home()
    .joinpath("Downloads")
    .joinpath("thao-le-hoang-v4zceVZ5HK8-unsplash.jpg"): ""
}
uploaded = {str(k): i for k, i in uploaded.items()}

# Read images with OpenCV.
images = {name: cv2.imread(name) for name in uploaded.keys()}

mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles

# Run MediaPipe Pose and plot 3d pose world landmarks.
with mp_pose.Pose(
    static_image_mode=True, min_detection_confidence=0.5, model_complexity=2
) as pose:
    for name, image in images.items():
        results = pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

mp_drawing.plot_landmarks(
        results.pose_world_landmarks,  mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
```

[image]

#### plotly `plot_landmarks()`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

_PRESENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.5
_VISIBILITY_THRESHOLD = 0.5


def plot_landmarks(
    landmark_list,
    connections=None,
):
    if not landmark_list:
        return
    plotted_landmarks = {}
    for idx, landmark in enumerate(landmark_list.landmark):
        if (
            landmark.HasField("visibility")
            and landmark.visibility < _VISIBILITY_THRESHOLD
        ) or (
            landmark.HasField("presence") and landmark.presence < _PRESENCE_THRESHOLD
        ):
            continue
        plotted_landmarks[idx] = (-landmark.z, landmark.x, -landmark.y)
    if connections:
        out_cn = []
        num_landmarks = len(landmark_list.landmark)
        # Draws the connections if the start and end landmarks are both visible.
        for connection in connections:
            start_idx = connection[0]
            end_idx = connection[1]
            if not (0 <= start_idx < num_landmarks and 0 <= end_idx < num_landmarks):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Landmark index is out of range. Invalid connection "
                    f"from landmark #{start_idx} to landmark #{end_idx}."
                )
            if start_idx in plotted_landmarks and end_idx in plotted_landmarks:
                landmark_pair = [
                    plotted_landmarks[start_idx],
                    plotted_landmarks[end_idx],
                ]
                out_cn.append(
                    dict(
                        xs=[landmark_pair[0][0], landmark_pair[1][0]],
                        ys=[landmark_pair[0][1], landmark_pair[1][1]],
                        zs=[landmark_pair[0][2], landmark_pair[1][2]],
                    )
                )
        cn2 = {"xs": [], "ys": [], "zs": []}
        for pair in out_cn:
            for k in pair.keys():
                cn2[k].append(pair[k][0])
                cn2[k].append(pair[k][1])
                cn2[k].append(None)

    df = pd.DataFrame(plotted_landmarks).T.rename(columns={0: "z", 1: "x", 2: "y"})
    df["lm"] = df.index.map(lambda s: mp_pose.PoseLandmark(s).name).values
    fig = (
        px.scatter_3d(df, x="z", y="x", z="y", hover_name="lm")
        .update_traces(marker={"color": "red"})
        .update_layout(
            margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
            scene={"camera": {"eye": {"x": 2.1, "y": 0, "z": 0}}},
        )
    )
    fig.add_traces(
        [
            go.Scatter3d(
                x=cn2["xs"],
                y=cn2["ys"],
                z=cn2["zs"],
                mode="lines",
                line={"color": "black", "width": 5},
                name="connections",
            )
        ]
    )

    return fig
```

#### try it

```
plot_landmarks(
        results.pose_world_landmarks,  mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
```

[image]

Comment: That's some neat piece of code you have written it'll take a while for my puny brain to comprehend this. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you have a proper solution to get this `mp_drawing.plot_landmarks(results.pose_world_landmarks,  mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS)` in real time to webcam video feed ?